# How to disable backups in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup

To test Windows 7 built-in backups, I set it to backup my documents drive to my external drive each night. However, it did not simply mirror the files, as I expected, but set up a complicated set of archives, etc...

Thus, I'd like to go back to the good old SyncBack software I used before. The problem is that I was able to cancel the sceduled task that backed my files up, but Windows 7 still reminds me each day to backup my files.

I did not find any option to simply disable the backups. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just disable the reminders about the backups in the Action Center?
Check out this post on [How To Geek](http://blogs.howtogeek.com/mysticgeek/2009/04/21/how-to-manage-action-center-in-windows-7/), many settings about the Action Center are explained.

In the Maintenance section, if next to Windows Backup, it says On, click to set it to "Not monitored".

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can turn them off (as I expect you've done), and disable the warnings in the Action Centre. That's the simplest answer.